# How can i debug MFC container properly with visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-debugging

i am using visual studio 2015 in large legacy project,
but when i try to debug a MFC container like CMap, CArray
i cannot succeed to see which elements the container has.

the only way that i can do it is to assign it to variable and watch the variable in specific key.

every time doing it it consume a lot of time of compiling and restart the tool.

is there a way to overcome this?

Many thanks
Noto

Answer (score 1):

You must create a custom [natvis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2015) debugger visualizer.